# PetaPoco ExplicitColumns does not work for derived class

Tags: inheritance, orm, petapoco

If I mark my pseudo-POCO class with ExplicitColumns and mark database column properties with Column attribute, PetaPoco still use properties from base class as if they are in database. Is there some way to avoid this? I dont want to use AutoMapper or other stuff to make pure POCOs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like simplest way is to inherit from base class and override its properties with Ignore attribute and then use this modified base class instead of original base class. Thank god that these properties were overridable.